Why __restrict often doesn't give optimization as expected?
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

void foo(int* a, int* b) {
  *a+=1;
  *b+=1;
  *a+=1;
}

void goo(int* __restrict a, int* b) {
  *a+=1;
  *b+=1;
  *a+=1;
}

void measure() {
  int x = 1;
  int y = 2;

  auto start_foo = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();  
 
  for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
    foo(&x, &y);
  }
  
  auto end_foo = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  
  
  std::chrono::duration<double> duration_foo = end_foo - start_foo;
  std::cout << "foo Runtime(secs): " << duration_foo.count() << std::endl;

  auto start_goo = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
    goo(&x, &y);
  }

  auto end_goo = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); 
  std::chrono::duration<double> duration_goo = end_goo - start_goo;

  std::cout << "goo Runtime(secs): " << duration_goo.count() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Without/With: " << duration_foo.count() / duration_goo.count() << std::endl << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    measure();
  }
}

I see that goo is optimized as expected via __restrict, but the output confused me a lot since there are cases when goo performs much more worse than foo. In 3/10 cases they perform similiarly, in 3/10 cases foo performs better, and only in 4/10 cases we have expected result.
Please, explain why?
foo(int*, int*):
        add     DWORD PTR [rdi], 1
        add     DWORD PTR [rsi], 1
        add     DWORD PTR [rdi], 1
        ret
goo(int*, int*):
        add     DWORD PTR [rsi], 1
        add     DWORD PTR [rdi], 2
        ret
.LC1:
        .string "foo Runtime(secs): "
.LC2:
        .string "goo Runtime(secs): "
.LC3:
        .string "Without/With: "
measure():
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 24
        call    std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::now()
        mov     rbx, rax
        call    std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::now()
        mov     edx, 19
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
        sub     rax, rbx
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        cvtsi2sdq       xmm0, rax
        divsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rsp], xmm0
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_insert<double>(double)
        mov     rbp, rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax-24]
        mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rbp+240+rax]
        test    rbx, rbx
        je      .L9
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rbx+56], 0
        je      .L7
        movsx   esi, BYTE PTR [rbx+67]
.L8:
        mov     rdi, rbp
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::put(char)
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::flush()
        call    std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::now()
        mov     rbx, rax
        call    std::chrono::_V2::system_clock::now()
        mov     edx, 19
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
        sub     rax, rbx
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        cvtsi2sdq       xmm0, rax
        divsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rsp+8], xmm0
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_insert<double>(double)
        mov     rbp, rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax-24]
        mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rbp+240+rax]
        test    rbx, rbx
        je      .L9
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rbx+56], 0
        je      .L10
        movsx   esi, BYTE PTR [rbx+67]
.L11:
        mov     rdi, rbp
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::put(char)
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::flush()
        mov     edx, 14
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC3
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        divsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_insert<double>(double)
        mov     rbp, rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax-24]
        mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rbp+240+rax]
        test    rbx, rbx
        je      .L9
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rbx+56], 0
        je      .L12
        movsx   esi, BYTE PTR [rbx+67]
.L13:
        mov     rdi, rbp
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::put(char)
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::flush()
        mov     rbp, rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax-24]
        mov     rbx, QWORD PTR [rbp+240+rax]
        test    rbx, rbx
        je      .L9
        cmp     BYTE PTR [rbx+56], 0
        je      .L14
        movsx   esi, BYTE PTR [rbx+67]
.L15:
        mov     rdi, rbp
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::put(char)
        add     rsp, 24
        pop     rbx
        mov     rdi, rax
        pop     rbp
        jmp     std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::flush()
.L7:
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbx]
        mov     esi, 10
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+48]
        cmp     rax, OFFSET FLAT:_ZNKSt5ctypeIcE8do_widenEc
        je      .L8
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    rax
        movsx   esi, al
        jmp     .L8
.L10:
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbx]
        mov     esi, 10
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+48]
        cmp     rax, OFFSET FLAT:_ZNKSt5ctypeIcE8do_widenEc
        je      .L11
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    rax
        movsx   esi, al
        jmp     .L11
.L12:
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbx]
        mov     esi, 10
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+48]
        cmp     rax, OFFSET FLAT:_ZNKSt5ctypeIcE8do_widenEc
        je      .L13
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    rax
        movsx   esi, al
        jmp     .L13
.L14:
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbx]
        mov     esi, 10
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax+48]
        cmp     rax, OFFSET FLAT:_ZNKSt5ctypeIcE8do_widenEc
        je      .L15
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    rax
        movsx   esi, al
        jmp     .L15
.L9:
        call    std::__throw_bad_cast()
main:
        push    rbx
        mov     ebx, 10
.L35:
        call    measure()
        sub     ebx, 1
        jne     .L35
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rbx
        ret
_GLOBAL__sub_I_foo(int*, int*):
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::__ioinit
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init() [complete object constructor]
        mov     edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:std::__ioinit
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::ios_base::Init::~Init() [complete object destructor]
        add     rsp, 8
        jmp     __cxa_atexit
.LC0:
        .long   0
        .long   1104006501

goo Runtime(secs): 7e-08
Without/With: 2.14286

foo Runtime(secs): 4e-08
goo Runtime(secs): 4e-08
Without/With: 1

foo Runtime(secs): 4e-08
goo Runtime(secs): 3e-08
Without/With: 1.33333

foo Runtime(secs): 4e-08
goo Runtime(secs): 3e-08
Without/With: 1.33333

foo Runtime(secs): 4e-08
goo Runtime(secs): 4e-08
Without/With: 1

foo Runtime(secs): 4e-08
goo Runtime(secs): 9e-08
Without/With: 0.444444

foo Runtime(secs): 3e-08
goo Runtime(secs): 4e-08
Without/With: 0.75

foo Runtime(secs): 4e-08
goo Runtime(secs): 4e-08
Without/With: 1

foo Runtime(secs): 3e-08
goo Runtime(secs): 4e-08
Without/With: 0.75

foo Runtime(secs): 4e-08
goo Runtime(secs): 3e-08
Without/With: 1.33333


Apart from everything else that's been said here, you should probably __restrict both parameters.

Actually, wherever I saw the usage of __restirct, it's been used only with one parameter.

The optimiser can see that your routine has no side effects and so annihilates it. The simplest way to get around this is to have foo and goo declared as returning an int and compute the sum of the return values. Even then you may have to add a conditional test (that you know will never be satisfied) and a printf of the result to get the most aggressive optimisers not to zap the benchmarked code inside the loop. For something as simple as summing consecutive integers I wouldn't put it past some of todays best optimising compilers to substitute the formula N*(N+1)/2.

Throwing in a volatile tells the optimizer that a read or write is absolutely necessary. That's a common way to selectively disable optimizations. But it directly interacts with __restrict - one tells the optimizer that reads can't be optimized, while the other says that the reads can be optimized. Here, if both a and b are made volatile, __restrict does nothing.

You could put the functions in another TU so that the compiler cannot see their definitions. Make sure to disable link-time optimization as well.

As the disassembly shows, the two high_resolution_clock::now() calls are separated by only a single mov, and that's to store the result of the first now(). Nothing is being measured.
The problem is that at -O3, the optimizer can see that your code does nothing. And at lower optimization levels, you would not be measuring anything meaningful. __restrict is explicitly intended for the optimizer. That explains why it's so rarely useful: Often the optimizer can optimize without it (superfluous) or the optimizer still can't optimize with it (insufficient).
